# Use enumerations (dropdowns) in variables of vNext build definitions (TFS)

Tags: tfs, build-definition, vnext

Is it possible to use dropdown menus for variables in `vNext` build definitions? And how can this be done?(`TFS 2017`)

Theses variables shall also be available at queue time. By default, all variables are of type string and cannot be changed (screenshot).

The usage is for example to select the build environment (win7/win10...)

This was possible with the old build system (XAML)(screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such setting in TFS to have a dropdown in variables of vNext build definitions, you can only change the value manually (For example, type `true` instead of `false` for system.debug variable).

I've submitted a user voice for your requirement at website below, you can vote it there:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32979130-use-dropdowns-in-variables-of-vnext-build-definiti